# What is the difference between mehr, weiter and noch?

Tags: difference

I have knowledge about those 3 words but I need more concrete examples to use them better while I am speaking.

- Kann ich mehr Wasser trinken?
- Kann ich noch ein/noch Wasser trinken?
- Kann ich noch mehr Wasser trinken ?

And I am not sure all of them are right. Could you translate them then what is the corresponding in english for those sentences?

Comment: Certainly the same as between _more_, _further_, and _still_ in English.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Sometimes "noch" translates to "yet", and adding to that "yet" can translate also to "schon" makes the English imho unpractical.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Dieser Hinweis nutzt nur jemanden, der gut Englisch kann. Du kannst nicht wissen, ob der Fragesteller diese Prämisse erfüllt.

Answer (score 4):

> And I am not sure all of them are right.

All of them are grammatically correct.

> Could you translate them then what is the corresponding in english for those sentences?

Sure. Your examples translate to English as follows

> - Kann ich mehr Wasser trinken?
>
>   > Can I drink more water?
> - Kann ich noch ein/noch Wasser trinken?
>
>   > Can I drink another water? / Can I still drink water?<sup>1</sup>
> - Kann ich noch mehr Wasser trinken ?
>
>   > Can I drink even more water?

---

If you simply want to ask politely for another water in a restaurant, or at a private supper, you would say:

> > Könnte ich noch ein Glas Wasser haben bitte.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Depends on context what makes sense.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

From the logical point of view it is pretty clear. All imply drinking more water than some reference quality (perhaps the water you have already  drank, or someone else has drank).

The second differs from the first in that we know that you are comparing to a non negligible quantity. Although it is a constructed case, if your  brother drinks nothing and you beg for a drop to drink, you can say:

> Darf ich mehr Wasser trinken?

Only after you have drunk something (typically not a drop) will you say:

> Darf ich noch Wasser trinken?

Then the difference gets blurry, but in principle the third form suggests you have already drunk more than the second, so it would be „even more“.